# Получить значение по дате

Tags: sql, postgresql

Вид таблицы из которой нужно вытащить значение:
id value dt
На входе есть штамп времени (dt_in), нужно достать из таблицы строку, штамп времени которого максимально приближен к dt_in, но он должен быть меньше его!

т.е. если имеется две строчки с 2021-05-11 12:00:00 и 2021-05-11 14:00:00,
а dt_in равно 2021-05-11 13:50:00
то необходимо вытащить вторую строку с штампом 2021-05-11 12:00:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE dt < dt_in
ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 1
```